# Import .csv data into a array

Tags: arrays, macos, csv, import, swift

I'm using Objective-C the last years. 
Now I'm trying the Xcode 6 beta 4 with swift.

I want to import a .csv form my webserver to an array. My old code in Objective-C was:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"https:// [URL] /versionen/versionen.csv";
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
if ( urlData )
{
    NSString *csvResponseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSArray         *MZVersionDatenZeilen = [csvResponseString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    NSEnumerator    *MZVersionEnumerator = [MZVersionDatenZeilen objectEnumerator];
    NSMutableArray  *MZVersionDatenArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[MZVersionDatenZeilen count]];
    NSString        *MZVersionZeile;
    while (MZVersionZeile = [MZVersionEnumerator nextObject])
    {
        [MZVersionDatenArray addObject:[MZVersionZeile componentsSeparatedByString:@";"]];
    }
}
```

How could I do this in Swift?
Is there a best practices - recommendation?

Comment: googlers, note that this QA is **many years old**.  a quick investigation (2017) shows that the only viable CSV library seems to be: https://github.com/Flinesoft/CSVImporter

Answer (score 14):

Every answer requires you to install/download a 3rd party utility, but that may not be optimal if the file you're working with is extremely simple or you work at an company that restricts 3rd party code.

So I figured I would just post incredibly basic, routine CSV file handling code that people can use as a base and modify as needed for simple CSV handling.

```
do {
    let file = try String(contentsOf: fileUrl)
    let rows = file.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
    for row in rows {
        let fields = row.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "").components(separatedBy: ",")
        print(fields)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

**This will handle any CSV files that you know won't have quotes and commas as part of the content of a field**, which in my case are most CSV files. Anything more complex than this, I recommend using one of the libraries posted in the other answers.

I just hope this saves someone a bit of typing.

Answer (score 13):

There are multiple swift libraries available:

[CSVImporter](https://github.com/Flinesoft/CSVImporter), which is an asynchronous parser suitable for working with large csv files.

```
let path = "path/to/your/CSV/file"
let importer = CSVImporter<[String]>(path: path)
importer.startImportingRecords { $0 }.onFinish { importedRecords in
    for record in importedRecords {
        // record is of type [String] and contains all data in a line
    }
}
```

[SwiftCSV](https://github.com/naoty/swiftcsv), which is a simple CSV parsing library for OSX and iOS.

```
let csvURL = NSURL(string: "users.csv")!
var error: NSErrorPointer = nil
let csv = CSV(contentsOfURL: csvURL, error: error)

// Rows
let rows = csv.rows
let headers = csv.headers  //=> ["id", "name", "age"]
let alice = csv.rows[0]    //=> ["id": "1", "name": "Alice", "age": "18"]
let bob = csv.rows[1]      //=> ["id": "2", "name": "Bob", "age": "19"]

// Columns
let columns = csv.columns
let names = csv.columns["name"]  //=> ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"]
let ages = csv.columns["age"]    //=> ["18", "19", "20"]
```

and [CSwiftV](https://github.com/Daniel1of1/CSwiftV), which is a csv parser conforming to [rfc4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-2) spec, but according to author it is all in memory so not suitable for large files.

```
let inputString = "Year,Make,Model,Description,Price\r\n1997,Ford,E350,descrition,3000.00\r\n1999,Chevy,Venture,another description,4900.00\r\n"
let csv = CSwiftV(String: inputString)

let headers = csv.headers // ["Year","Make","Model","Description","Price"]
let rows = csv.rows 
// [
//  ["1997","Ford","E350","descrition","3000.00"],
//  ["1999","Chevy","Venture","another description","4900.00"]
// ]
```

Comment: I had to do this to find the file in my project:
var urlpath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("users", ofType: "csv")
let csvURL:NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(urlpath!)!

Comment: Downvoted because SwiftCSV is not a proper implementation of a CSV parser. There's many others, one I found that worked for me was CSwiftV  - found here: https://github.com/Daniel1of1/CSwiftV

Comment: This library has been deprecated by the author.

Answer (score 9):

Don't use SwiftCSV as per the currently most upvoted answer.

SwiftCSV does not handle double quotes as of right now so if any data in your CSV file has line breaks or commas in it, SwiftCSV won't work. And you might waste valuable development time finding out exactly why it doesn't work ... to save you that time, just use another library.

The **CSwiftV** library worked very well for me:
https://github.com/Daniel1of1/CSwiftV

It handles quoted text, newlines, commas, worked like a charm on my data. It also has unit tests and conforms to the [rfc4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-2) standard.

Answer (score 3):

I **recommend using [CSVImporter](https://github.com/Flinesoft/CSVImporter)** – it takes care of things like **quoted text** (following [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)) for you and even handles **very large files** without problems.

Compared to other solutions it works both **asynchronously** (prevents delays) and **reads your CSV file line by line** instead of loading the entire String into memory (prevents memory issues). On top of that it is **easy to use** and provides **beautiful callbacks** for indicating failure, progress, completion and even **data mapping** if you desire to.

---

The **simplest way of using it** is this (gives you each line as an array of Strings):

```
let path = "path/to/your/CSV/file"
let importer = CSVImporter<[String]>(path: path)
importer.startImportingRecords { $0 }.onFinish { importedRecords in
    for record in importedRecords {
        // record is of type [String] and contains all data in a line
    }
}
```

Take advantage of **more sophisticated features** like data mapping and progress callbacks:

```
let path = "path/to/Hogwarts/students"
let importer = CSVImporter<Student>(path: path)
importer.startImportingRecords { recordValues -> Student in
    
    // define your data mapping here
    return Student(firstName: recordValues[0], lastName: recordValues[1])
    
}.onProgress { importedDataLinesCount in
    
    // use this to indicate progress
    print("\(importedDataLinesCount) lines were already imported.")
    
}.onFinish { importedRecords in
    for student in importedRecords {
        // now importedRecords is an array of Student objects
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the pointer buddy. yeah, it seems to be the way to go for large local files. I wonder if you've tried it when getting csv from the net? any gotchas?  Cheers

Comment: I've tried to make this RFC 4180 compliant. I'm sure though that there are many CSV files in the net that don't comply to the standard and are named "CSV file" anyway, so there'll probably be such cases. Also this library is relatively new and I didn't release my app yet for which I wrote it, so I can't guarantee it'll work for 99% or something like that. Feel free to improve it though, that's why it's open source. :)

Comment: the fact that you focus on Carthage is enough to make me use it :)

Comment: @JoeBlow I'm not sure I understand your question correctly and if it is a feature request on the CSVImporter library then I would suggest you to open an issue on GitHub so we can discuss and implement it there. Anyway, this is how I understand it (feel free to correct me in the description of the GitHub issue): You have an API that gives you a String which is similar to the content of a CSV file and you want to use CSVImporter to get data from this single String object? Well, that should be possible, although it would not be read "line by line" anymore as you're providing the entire String ...

Comment: Correct, I'm just providing the entire string. (As it happens, I will be doing that "many times".)  Sounds like it should be fine, thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134870/discussion-between-dschee-and-joe-blow).